# Eigenvalues of time dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, observables

Consider the Schrödinger equation $H\Psi=i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}({\bf r},t)$. The hamiltonian $H$ is:
\begin{equation}
H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V({\bf r},t)
\end{equation}
And the equation is:
\begin{equation}
\Big[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V({\bf r},t) \Big]\Psi({\bf r},t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}({\bf r},t)
\end{equation}

If $V$ is time-independent, then $H$ too. In this case the wave function can be factored as $\Psi({\bf r},t)=\psi({\bf r})e^{-i\omega t}$, and then $H\Psi=E\Psi$, so the eigenvalues of $H$ are the energies $E$.

If $V$ is time-dependent, we can't separate the variables ${\bf r}$ and  $t$ like before, but $H$ is still an hermitian operator and it must have certain eigenvalues.

My question is: What are the eigenvalues of $H$ when it depends on time? (and if they are the energies, why?)

EDIT: If I try to separate the variables, I have $\Psi({\bf r},t)=\psi({\bf r})\varphi(t)$, putting this in Schrödinger equation ([this is the method of separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations)):
\begin{equation}
\Big[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V({\bf r},t) \Big]\psi({\bf r})\varphi(t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[\psi({\bf r})\varphi(t)]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
-\varphi(t)\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi({\bf r})+V({\bf r},t)\psi({\bf r})\varphi(t)=i\hbar\psi({\bf r})\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}(t)
\end{equation}
Dividing by $\Psi({\bf r},t)=\psi({\bf r})\varphi(t)$:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{1}{\psi({\bf r})}\nabla^2\psi({\bf r})+V({\bf r},t)=i\hbar\frac{1}{\varphi(t)}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}(t)
\end{equation}
But I can't continue with the method, because the left side depends on $t$ (it doesn't depend on ${\bf r}$ only).

Comment: why exactly can you not separate $r$ and $t$?  $r$ is not a position, it's a coordinate so it doesn't depend on $t$....

Comment: I can't apply the method of separation of variables to factor the wavefunction in two wavefunctions (one depending only on $r$ and the other depending only on $t$), I edited the question whit some details

Comment: of course... I should have realized this is what you meant... my bad.  Sorry.

Comment: Have you reviewed [Dirac's approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-dependent_perturbation_theory)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I haven't seen Dirac's approach yet

Comment: You could solve the differential equation if you have to, but a better method would be to expand the states into a linear superposition of stationary States.  This approach is given here in detail. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-74-introductory-quantum-mechanics-ii-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT5_74s09_lec02.pdf

Comment: Or, you could split your potential into a function of time and position separately, assuming that they are independent and solve the equation by separation of variables.

Comment: The quantum chaos guys introduce a concept of 'quasi-energies' which might be related to this problem. I never found good literature on this though.

Comment: It's the link I gave you above: time-dependent perturbation theory, available in your QM text, I'm sure. The whole point of eigenstates is because they time evolve simply; but when they don't, as you are suggesting, don't bother---you just follow the book.